# To boil frozen food with chicken without microwave

Tags: chicken, microwave, defrosting

Assume you have microwave food dishes with chicken and you have no microwave.

**What is the recommended time to boil the food?**
The temperature is less than microwave can reach.
I think the time should be longer, but how much?

Comment: What is the food? Is it something water based, like soup/stew?

Comment: Food is chicken with rice and vegetables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no recommended time. You just cook it until it is done.

If the food is pre-cooked (which is common with microwave-ready food), you only have to bring it to the temperature you like to eat it at. Else, you cook it until whatever is inside is cooked through. You can use a thermometer to determine the exact moment, but I wouldn't bother for a microwave-ready dish, as it is unlikely to be sensitive to overcooking.

Answer (score 1):

Microbiologicaly there would be a thread of contamination with certain bacteria (Salmonella Typhimurium, Campylobacter) if the chicken would be raw. This is unlikely for a microwave meal, I think. As long as the meal isn't spoiled, doesn't smell or look funny, you just need to cook (fry roast...) the food until it is hot. If the rice is too hard to eat afterwards you could add a few spoons of water after you roasted it a minute.
JMTC